# Как правильно организовать процесс CI?

Tags: azure, teamcity

Планирую организовать процесс следующим образом:

- Пушим код в репозиторий GitLab.
- Виртуальная машина на Azure c развернутым TeamCity. Получаем изменения, выполняем сборку пакетов, билд, тесты.
- Деплой на другую виртуальную машину где будет Staging.
- После проверки на Staging деплой на продакшн.

Вроде бы все логично, но смущает необходимость развертывания двух дополнительных виртуалок. Можно ли деплоить просто в другую папку на той же виртуалке и насторить в IIS ее как отдельный сайт?

Comment: по-хорошему бинари надо хранирь в бинарной репозиторий. потом оттуда брать и деплоить куда хочешь.

Comment: TeamCity может хранить бинари в артефактах конфигурации, если память позволяет это делать. Далее другие конфигурации ссылаются на эту конфигурацию и берут артефакты. таким образом, тебе не нужно хранить 2 ВМ. Также можно в TeamCity все хранить в VCS: настройки, изменения... это своего рода бэкап

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, про настройки и изменения понял, а вот насчет артефактов можно подробнее? Правильно ли я понимаю, что артефакты это то, что было сдеплоено MSBuild и является своего рода копией деплоя сделанной TeamCity?

Comment: да. правильно. все, что идет на деплой, все исполняемые файлы и не только, которые остаются после билда и нужно сохранить - артефакты.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону App Services или старых Cloud Services - там есть staging, которй можно просто переключить в прод, без необходимости заново деплоить. Кстати, в azure обычные VM - это самый неудобный для управления вариант. Все фишки платформы так раскрываются при использовании готовых paas решений, вроде App Services. А без них - это просто очень дорогой хостинг виртуалок :)

Comment: @PashaPash, наверное вы правы, но уже все заработало на основе ВМ. С точки зрения нынешнего опыта, оказывается не так сложно было все настроить. Но когда я этот вопрос задавал, столкнулся в первый раз со всей этой инфраструктурой.

Comment: @PashaPash, кстати, я вот не пойму как настроить тот же TeamCity на основе AppServices, там ведь нет пользовательского интерфейса как я понимаю?

Comment: @andrey.shedko TeamCity - не получится настроить. На AppServices удобно хостить свои приложения, а не чужие. Там даже встроенный CI есть, который вполне справляется с забрать с гитхаба/сбилдовать/задеплоить